# return string inside block of NSURLConnection - Incompatible block pointer types sending

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsurlconnection

I am trying to isolate logic responsible for authentication and retriving the TOKEN inside the function. I have the problem with returning the string with token from BLOCK of NSURLConnetcion.

It causues `semantic error`: Incompatible block pointer types sending

```
'NSString *(^)(NSURLResponse *__strong, NSData *__strong, NSError *__strong)'
```

to parameter of type

```
'void (^)(NSURLResponse *__strong, NSData *__strong, NSError *__strong)'
```

I am completly newbie to Objective-C, so please be forgiving. Below is my function.

```
- (NSString*)getToken: (NSString *)username andPassword: (NSString *) password {

NSMutableURLRequest *request1 = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:
[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth_ex"]
cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:20];

__block NSString * tokens;
[request1 setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString * body1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"email=%@&password=%@",username,password];

[request1 setHTTPBody: [body1 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSOperationQueue * queue1 = [[NSOperationQueue alloc]init];

[NSURLConnection
 sendAsynchronousRequest:request1 queue:queue1 completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
     if ([data length] >0 && connectionError == nil){
         NSDictionary* token = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
         tokens = [token objectForKeyedSubscript:@"token"];
         return tokens;
     }
     else{
         return @"NOT AUTHORIZEd";
     }
 }];


}
```

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Returning method object from inside block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22267865/returning-method-object-from-inside-block)

Comment: You need to reconsider your approach as your method can't return something that is asynchronously downloaded...

Comment: @Wain I think reasonable will be to change to synchronus request, because of simply fact: before other requests will be done we need token. What do you think about it?

Comment: I would not change to synchronous. I would trigger the next required action in the asynchronous callback...

Comment: `I would trigger the next required action in the asynchronous callback...` I know that this is outside of the scope of this quesiton, but could you link me to some example how to do it.

Comment: I know of no direct example. It's just calling the method that will use the token when it has been received...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of issues.

- [Naming Conventions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Conventions/Conventions.html)
- Your method `getToken:andPassword:` should be asynchronous.
- Improper use of `NSOperationQueue` (you don't need that)
- No Content-Type header specified
- Omitting parameter encoding in the Query component of the URI (`x-www-form-urlencoded`)
- Some lack of experience which `NSURLConnection`:

  Don't use class convenience methods unless you know exactly that your request works with the implemented default behavior (for requests with authentication this is almost always never the case). Please read the official docs

  - [sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001697-SW10)
  - [URL Loading System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165i)

So, for a solution, I would suggest the delegate approach of either `NSURLConnection` or `NSURLSession`. See examples and code snippets in the official docs already mentioned above.

You will have to handle an authentication challenge, where you provide the credentials. This also frees you from the error prone and inconvenient need to percent encode the parameters if you would put them into the URL or the body.

You should also use `https`.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `tokens` is declared outside of the block but accessible from inside the block.  Therefore the `if` statement doesn't need to `return tokens` and the else statement should just be `tokens = @"NOT AUTHORIZED";`

Note that your block is being called from some framework code, and that code doesn't expect anything to be returned, hence the completionHandler is declared as `void`, and you aren't allowed to return values from a `void` function.

---

I should add that the `sendAsynchronousRequest` method will return almost immediately, but the completion handler won't be called until sometime later, after the server responds to the request. So typically the completion handler is used to notify the main thread that the operation has completed.  One way to notify the main thread is with code like this

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(someMethod:) withObject:tokens waitUntilDone:NO];
```

where the `someMethod` method is declared as

```
- (void)someMethod:(NSString *tokens)
{
}
```

That way, you can do something with the results after the network request has finished.