# IOS JSON authorization

Tags: ios, json

my api answer: {"response":"success"}

So, if "success" - the user will be logged

Code:

```
NSString *stringURL = @"........";
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:stringURL];
    NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urlData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    if ([[json objectForKey:@"response"] isEqual:@"success"])
        return true;
    else
        return false;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hard to say with basically no information. You don't say what the JSON data is that you receive, you don't say what json or error contain. Have you heard of NSLog?

Comment: I have only two JSON answers: {"response":"success"} or {"response":"not success"}.

Comment: I want to get true if "success" and false if "not success"

Comment: Objective c uses YES or NO for boolean make me wonder how you compile this code

Comment: I didn't ask what replies you expect. I asked what replies you are actually getting. Since your code doesn't work, something is not as expected. Therefore, posting what you expect is quite pointless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put **NSlog** and Check What is the response

> Also use "**isEqualToString**"  insted of "**isEqual**"

```
NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"Your URL"];
NSLog(@"myURL =%@", myURL);
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
 {
    //  check the list of status codes here :http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#2xx_Success

     if ([(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode]==200)
     {
         NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
         NSLog(@"Response from Server in string  =%@", jsonString);
         id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
         NSLog(@"Response from Server in JSON object =%@", jsonObject);
         if ([[jsonObject objectForKey:@"response"] isEqualToString:@"success"])
            // Write code for True
         else
          // Write code for False
     }
     else
     {
         // Some Error
     }
 }];
```

Comment: @arturdev yeah i m aware of that. actually codes starting with 2 are used for success.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#2xx_Success

Comment: Thanks! But I can not to compile it. error on line [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)

Comment: Incompatible block pointer types sending 'int (^)(NSURLResponse *__strong, NSData *__strong, NSError *__strong)' to parameter of type 'void (^)(NSURLResponse *__strong, NSData *__strong, NSError *__strong)'

Comment: I think here is the same problem and solution for it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22891929/return-string-inside-block-of-nsurlconnection-incompatible-block-pointer-types

Comment: Thanks!!

But, next problem: 

Response from Server in string  =<?xml version="1.0"?>
<response>
  <item>{"response":"success"}</item>
</response>
2014-06-19 00:15:43.897 All Social Accounts[8297:60b] Response from Server in JSON object =(null)

Comment: The output is not proper JSON, its a xml so, you are not getting JSON object.

the Output must be only like below :
{"response":"success"}